# iTunesConnect Bundle ID freaking me out

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app in my ituneconnect account. I changed its bundle ID. It still shows the older ID in app details. but when I validate my binary it says that you Bundle ID doent match as its been updated to new one.

I want to revert to old one again but it doesnt give me a option to select the older bundle ID. As in Edit option it shows the older one selected and the actual current one doesnt appears.

Let me make it more clear. I have 3 bundle Ids option - 1,2,3

The time I created application I added Bundle ID-2
Then I changed it to 3 by mistake

Still in app details it shows 2 as current bundle ID, Now there are just two options - 1,2
When I try to upload my binary it says that you have bundle ID 3 selected on iTunesConnect

Does anyone having similar issue

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the bundle ID of an app in iTunes connect. (It appears to be an absolutely unmodifiable field in Apple's database.) So you must have two different apps, and might be using (attempting to update) the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I read the same at apple guidelines, but I am able to modify this field, The issue I every option I modified to becomes the previously selected one. there is no way I can select the actual one ... anyways I have uploaded my code as new application.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I am assuming you are trying to change the bundle id not in xcode, but on iTunesConnect.apple.com and that your app was built with the new bundle id that you dont want to use.

If that is the case, here's what you should do:

- Go to XCode, select the target, and select the Summary tab.
- Change the bundle id
- build and use application loader to submit the same (after verifying 
  the app) making sure that you have setup the app (you want to update) with the old bundle id for update.

Hope this helps!